# Update date to database in vb

Tags: vb.net, sql-server-2008, tableadapter

Everytime I wish to update the date into a database, It comes with this error

```
Conversion from type 'DataRowView' to type 'String' is not valid
```

Here is my code

```
      Me.Validate()
      Me.DisplayLoanBindingSource.EndEdit()
      Me.TableAdapterManager.UpdateAll(Me.LibraryDataSet)
      frmLibrary.DisplayLoanTableAdapter.Fill(frmLibrary.LibraryDataSet.DisplayLoan)
```

Comment: where's the code you use to get the date value?

Comment: 'Me.DisplayLoanTableAdapter.Fill(Me.LibraryDataSet.DisplayLoan)'

Answer (score 0):

Try dropping DisplayLoan on the Fill statement.

```
frmLibrary.DisplayLoanTableAdapter.Fill(frmLibrary.LibraryDataSet)
```

Comment: That should probably be a different question..but while we're on the topic, did you update the DataGridView's DataSource and rebind after using the Fill method?